# *ngFor in Angular for multiple div

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

is It possible to write in HTML:

```
<div class="" >
    <div class="container-fluid" *ngFor="let Title of projectTitle">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12" >
                <div class="card" >
                    <div class="body text-center" >
                        <h3 class="m-b-0">{{Title}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this div multiple times: which is get from database

Comment: why not just give it a try? This will quickly tell you if it is possible or not.

Comment: Without seeing the data source no one can say if this will work, but yes, that looks fine. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your data structure.

If your **projectTitle** is a collection of strings, then it will work as you intended.

But if it is a array of object then you will just need to use

```
<h3 class="m-b-0">{{ Title.nameOfTheKey }}</h3>
```